# Vagrant push to ftp not working

Tags: file-upload, ftp, vagrant, push, vagrantfile

So i am trying to push my files via Vagrant push to an ftp server.
But I am getting an Error where I don't really know what to do.

When I do an vagrant push I'am getting this output.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/pushes/ftp/push.rb:20:in `push': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:655:in `push'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/plugins/commands/push/command.rb:28:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:54:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:275:in `cli'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/bin/vagrant:156:in `<main>'
```

and this is the config in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.push.define "ftp" do |push|
   push.host = "*****.********.com"
   push.username = "******"
   push.password = "***********"
   push.destination = "/dev/raumbuchung"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know what the Problem was.

It seems that the data that I wanted to push was to much to handle.
I tried to push with excluding some Files.
And per try and error I got that the problem was one Folder that contained a lot of files. So excluding that folder worked for me.